# How to bind a List<Int> to a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview

This might be quite a strange question since usually people bind only complex types to a gridview. But I need to bind a List of Int (the same is for strings).
Usually, as the property to bind one uses the name of the property of the object, but when using a Int or a String, the value is exactly the object itself, not a property.

What is the "name" to get the value of the object? I tried "Value", "" (empty), "this", "item" but no luck.

I'm referring to a gridview in a web form.

**Update**

There's a related Stack Overflow question, *[How to bind a List to a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720349/how-to-bind-a-listdatetime-to-a-gridview)*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<BoundField DataField="!" />` may do the trick (since `BoundField.ThisExpression` equals "!").

Answer (score 7):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: With GridView, when using the bind column, you just specify the name. This is good for repeater or with custom columns

Comment: Could you use a TemplateField

Comment: Actually Container will not work
You have to get <%# GetDataItem.ToString() %> which is a undocumented method that gets the DataItem

Comment: Aside from the most simple solution by @Andrey Shchekin, this is useful when the resulting display value is more involved than just the value, like a link or Text containing the value.

Answer (score 3):

I expect you might have to put the data into a wrapper class - for example:

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    public T Value {get;set;}
    public Wrapper() {}
    public Wrapper(T value) {Value = value;}
}
```

Then bind to a `List<Wrapper<T>>` instead (as `Value`) - for example using something like (C# 3.0):

```
var wrapped = ints.ConvertAll(
            i => new Wrapper<int>(i));
```

or C# 2.0:

```
List<Wrapper<int>> wrapped = ints.ConvertAll<Wrapper<int>>(
    delegate(int i) { return new Wrapper<int>(i); } );
```

Comment: That was my first approach, but I remember that once I used a specific name to get the value.
I guess I've to digg into reflector :)

Comment: Quite a complicated solution in my opinion. Look at my answer for a simpler version of the same idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same idea as Marc's, but simpler.

It creates an anonymous wrapper class that you can use as the grid's datasource, and then bind the column to the "Value" member:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4};
var wrapped = (from i in list select new { Value = i }).ToArray();
grid.DataSource = wrapped;
```

Comment: Fine for 1-way binding, at least.

Answer (score -1):

If you have to write a property name to be rendered, you have to encapsulate the integer (or string) value in a class with a property that returns the value. In the grid you only have to write `<%# Eval("PropertyName") %>`.

Comment: but the Int doesn't have a PropertyName :)

Comment: Yes, but you have to create a class like that:
<code>
class MyInt
{
public int myValue;
public int MyValue
{
get{ return myValue; }
}
}
</code>