# How to bind a List<DateTime> to a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I already read Stack Overflow question *[How to bind a List to a gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515464/how-to-bind-a-listint-to-a-gridview)*.

But I need to bind a List<DateTime> to a gridview, but MAINLY I also want be able to access the DateTime value from within a ItemTemplate. How do I do that? When I was working with a DataTable, I used to do it like that:

```
<%# Eval("SDIndex") %>
```

How would I do it linking it directly to the List<DateTime>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(x => new DateTime(2011, 4, x)).ToList();
        grd.DataSource = dates;
        grd.DataBind();
    }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# ((DateTime)GetDataItem()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This should also work:

```
<%# string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", GetDataItem()) %>
```