# Best way to display data in a gridview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005

I have data of the format

```
Filename   Status
abc.txt     Found
xyz.txt     Not Found
```

I need to display it on a gridview.

- How do I hold these values in?
- Should I use a multidimensional array or other collections?
- Which one would be best suited?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Are you reading the file system, or getting it from a database, or getting it from somewhere else?

Comment: How about dictionary? File name could be the key.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention it.. I am checking if the file exists using System.IO.File.Exists. The filenames come from a .csv file and i search for the filenames if its found then i want to place found against the file name else Notfound

Comment: @reniuz Yes, Dictionary should do i guess... just wanted to know the best practice in this situation

Comment: @Praby It won't be if you'll have not unique file names

Comment: @reniuz yes.. you are right... can i have 1 key and multiple values for that key. Then i can have a sl no as the key.. and the filename and status are values... Not sure if that is possible

Comment: @Praby because you are not shore that your all file names will be unique, you should use Samidjo answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collections are best suited. Create a File class where you can put your fields like this:

```
class File
{
    private string _fileName;

    public string fileName{
       get { return _fileName;}
           set { _fileName= value;}
    }

        private string _status;

    public string status{
       get { return _status;}
       set { _status= value;}
    }
}
```

Then you add every instance to a list.

```
    /* Create Instances */
    GridView grid = new GridView();
    List<File> files = new List<File>();

    /* create and fill File instance */
    File f = new File();
    f.status = "WhatEverString";
    f.fileName = "WhatEverString";

    /* Add file instance to the list*/
    files.add(f);

    /* Bind data to GridView*/
    grid.DataSource = Files;
    grid.DataBind();
```

Now we only have to refer to every field to its place in ASP side, Stack Overflow question *[How to bind a List to a gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515464/how-to-bind-a-listint-to-a-gridview)* should help.

Comment: create a list List<File> fileList = new List<File>();. Then File newEntry = new File(){fileName = "abc.txt", status="Found"}; and add to list: fileList.Add(newEntry);

Answer (score 2):

A [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) or Array/List of [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure that your file names are unique you can use a dictionary as IndigoDelta mentioned, but check if the key already exist before adding new entry:

```
Dictionary<string, string> files = new Dictionary<string,string>();
string status = "Not Found";
if (File.Exists("abc.txt"))
   status = "Found";

//Check if key exists
if (files.ContainsKey("abc.txt"))
   files.Add("abc.txt", status);
else
   files["abc.txt"] = status;
```